# Add a space every two characters in R

Tags: r, regex

I have phone numbers in the form of:

```
0123456789
```

and I'd like to make them look like

```
01 23 45 67 89
```

So far, adding a zero is no big deal with the `paste0` function, but I'd like something a bit simpler than a long chain of nested `paste0` and `substr`. Something might be possible with a regex reading every two digits, but I don't see how to make it happen.

Comment: How come you want to get `01` if you have `1` at the start? Do you mean you need to check if the string contains an even number of digits, and if not, prepend the value with `0` and then insert spaces?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think the OP incorrectly entered the test string.  I've updated with what I think was the intention.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, but what is the expected behavior for `123456789`?

Comment: All my numbers have nine digits. After adding the first zero with `paste0('0', x)`, I'd like to insert a space between every two digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the regex expression `(.{2})` with `\\1`.  Note that there is also a trailing whitespace problem, since we don't want to add an extraneous extra space at the end of the string for inputs with an even quantity of digits.  To handle this, we can just remove trailing whitespace from our replaced string.

```
x <- '0123456789'
y <- sub("\\s+$", "", gsub('(.{2})', '\\1 ', x))
y
[1] "01 23 45 67 89"
```

## Demo

Comment: What whitespace are you talking about :) ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If we replace every two characters by those characters with a post-appended space, then we hose ourselves for the final 2 characters (unless we want a dangling space at the end).  I wish R had a nicer string trim function like Java, Python, and other languages.  Alas, I used an ugly second call to `sub()` to handle this.

Comment: R has a `trimws` function. But there is no whitespace in the input, thus, there won't be any whitespace at the end after replacing with `gsub('(.{2})', '\\1 ', x)`

Answer (score 4):

Without regex:

```
x <- "0123456789"
formatC(as.numeric(x), big.mark = " ", big.interval = 2, 
        format = "d", flag = "0", width = nchar(x))
#[1] "01 23 45 67 89"
```

Comment: Interesting solution! What does the `flag` parameter stand for? I find the R Documentation quite unclear (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/formatC)

Comment: It's a format modifier and `"0"` indicates padding (to the given width) with leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit package-heavy solution than Tim's but you can do something like this with `dplyr` and `stringr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
original_string %>% 
  paste0(0, .) %>% # add 0 to the head
  str_replace_all("(.{2})", "\\1 ") %>% # insert spaces after every to digits
  str_trim() # remove the space in the end if it's there
```