# Error in converting character to time variable in r with Lubridate packages

Tags: r, lubridate

Thanks for your help.

One of variable in my dataset looks like this:

```
> df$TM
> [1] "000054" "000020" "000056" "000051" "000025" "000116" "000219" "000207" "000233" "000206" "000142" "000126" "000237" "000215" "000236" "000246" "000219"
 [18] "000227" "000803" "000920"...
```

The real meaning of each character is hours, minutes and seconds.

When I adjust hms function in Lubridates as follows

```
> df$TM <- hms(df$TM)
```

> Warning message is coming: "In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
> Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs"

After that, all the values in the column changes to NA.

I also tried

```
> df$TM <- as.POSIXct(df$TM, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

and

```
> df$TM <- chronicle(times = df$TM)
```

and

```
> df$TM <- strptime(df$TM, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

but... these three trial also have same results.

(Actually all data has changed to NA, so warning message is same as error message to me)

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417716/add-a-space-every-two-characters-in-r) to include a semicolon after every second element. After that you can transform the resulting character string as date (with day, month and year) or leave it as is.

For completeness, the solution for your problem then is

```
 as.POSIXct(sub(":+$", "", gsub('(.{2})', '\\1:', df$TM)), format = "%H:%M:%S")
```